# C++ WinAPI waveOutGetVolume

Tags: c++, winapi, c++builder

My program needs to retrieve the volume information. I have been using various ways of `waveOutGetVolume()` but having no luck retireving a value between 0 and 100.

I have tried using HIWORD and LOWORD values aswell.

For example my volume is currently at 14%. My Program displays a completely random number.

```
DWORD volume;
HWAVEOUT hwo;
waveOutGetVolume(hwo, &volume);
```

Could someone tell me where I am going wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the return value? Is this your actual code, and if so, why don't you initialize hwo? From MSDN: hwo -
Handle to an open waveform-audio output device. This parameter can also be a device identifier.

Comment: [The documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909806.aspx) says that 0xFFFF means full volume and 0x0000 means silence. You won't get a value between 0 and 100.

Comment: Yes i did see this. Is there a possible way to retrieve a percentage between these? however i am getting 74579396 as my max volume

Comment: `returned value / 0xFFFF` -> percent of max volume. `volume` is a DWORD. The result is in the low order word.

Comment: ^This gives me 665 at maximum volume

Comment: Have you called `waveOutOpen()` to get a handle to the audio device (i.e. initialize `hwo`)? Also, like @steveg89 said, check your return values to see what error `waveOutGetVolume()` may be returning.

Comment: I did initialize `HWAVEOUT` earlier im not sure if i have done it correctly. How do i need to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Read [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa909806.aspx) carefully, it says:

> pdwVolume
>
> Pointer to a variable to be filled with the current volume setting. The low-order word of this location contains the left-channel volume setting, and the high-order word contains the right-channel setting. A value of 0xFFFF represents full volume, and a value of 0x0000 is silence.
>
> If a device does not support both left and right volume control, the low-order word of the specified location contains the mono volume level.

So, you'll need to bit-and the result with the appropriate mask:

```
DWORD volume;
HWAVEOUT hwo;
// retrieve the handle
waveOutGetVolume(hwo, &volume);
// don't forget to check for errors

WORD left_channel_volume = volume & 0xffff;           // extract the low order word
WORD right_channel_volume = (volume >> 16) & 0xffff;  // extract the high order word

unsigned left_volume_percent = left_channel_volume / 0xffff;
```